# need help making a c program that reads flow meter

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, programming, microchip

For the past week, i've just started my first ever project to make a C program for a PIC16F877A under MikroC, where I would get pulses in from the flow meter and calculate the flow rate, then output it to the lcd.

However, when i connected it to PORTD of the PIC16f877A RD0, it gave random values everytime that go up and down on the lcd. What's wrong?

Water flow meter [datasheet](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/sensors/YF-S201.pdf) and program:

```
void main() { 
     volatile unsigned int value;
     char str [20];
     double calc;
     lcd_init();        //initiallise lcd
     ADC_Init();         // and to read in values
     TRISD.f0=1;        //setting the signal input
     PORTD.F0=0;
     while (1)
     {
      if (PORTD.F0= 1)   //if water flows through the meter
      {
       value = ADC_read(PORTD.F0);  //read from RD0 and assign to value read
       delay_ms(100);                 //delay so i could see value on screen
       calc = (value * 60 / 7.5);     //calculation to show flow per minute

       byteToStr(calc,str);
       lcd_out (1,1, str);      //output to screen
       value++;
      }

     }


}
```

Comment: For starters, `if (PORTD.F0= 1)` should be `if (PORTD.F0==1)`: it's a condition, not a declaration. For the rest, a few things are unclear to me. Are the values actually _moving_ on the LCD? That may indicate a problem in the LCD wiring. And did you check with a multimeter that the values on the analog port are actually more or less constant? This is important to check, of course. I also think that the part doing the calculations isn't correct, for example `value++` doesn't have any effect because `value` is overwritten in the next loop. But it's not clear what it's supposed to do.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. i have just now edited it , what i get on the lcd screen is a value that goes up to just over 200 hundred and goes back down again, i want it to continously go up as i am measuring the flow rate in milli litres...im still confused

Comment: i have also changed value++ to calc++.

Comment: Also `calc++` doesn't do much because also `calc` gets a new value assigned in the next loop: `calc = (value * 60 / 7.5)`. By the way, if you edit your code, please [edit] your question as well, so that we have the latest info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why it seems to you that you should be doing ADC reads to get your value.

What you need to be doing is counting the pulses from the meter per unit of time. So maybe you should be setting up an interrupt that comes once per second. Also setup a timer/counter channel in counter mode to increment once each time a pulse comes in from the meter. At each second you capture the counter value and re-zero for the counter for the next interval. The count of pulses per second is a direct reading of Hz and can be related to flow rate via the data sheet table.

Comment: ok, so shall i do both? counter and an interrups?

Comment: Yes. You need both. The counter busily accumulates the pulses from the meter. Hopefully your MCU has some timer/counter resources you can use for this. The interrupt establishes the interval over which you gather the pulse count. I had suggested your using one second interval. Most likely you will find that you are using a second timer/counter channel in timer mode to generate the once per second interrupt.

Comment: awesome! one other question, the flow meter has one 3 wires, gnd, Vcc and signal, that which pin should i connect that on the pic16f877a?

Comment: I also suggest that you start off designing this the correct way and have the interrupt service routine do just the simplest of things. It retrieves the current count from the counter channel and places it into a global variable. It then zeros out the counter. It can then set a handshake flag to indicate to the main loop that the next reading is available. Finally the interrupt routine may need to so something to assure the next one second interrupt will happen. (Not all MCU timer interrupts work the same so I cannot tell you what would be required for this last step).

Comment: You connect the pulse pin of the flow meter to the MCU pin that is capable is being the counter input!! This will require that you study the MCU data sheet / user manual to see how this needs to be configured. All MCU types are different so you'll have to figure out yours.